# How to show documentation for Django via ST2?

Tags: python, django, documentation, sublimetext2

I'd like to use Sublime Text 2 for my django developing environment. But When I type the following code:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

I found that the autocomplete plugin can help me find the keyword like `models` or `CharField`, but how can I get the documentation of these keywords, specifically, the meaning and amount of each param in a function?

I've installed the `SublimeCodeIntel` plugin, but when I right-clicked on the function name and chose `Rope:Get Documentation`, it said **no documentation found for ...**, so what should I do now? Any advice would be appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Zeal package](https://github.com/vaanwd/Zeal) for that if you're on Linux or Windows and [DashDoc package](https://github.com/farcaller/DashDoc) if you're on OS X. Easy to use, but require third party software. They both have Python and Django documentation.

There is a third one that doesn't require third party software but does not offer great usability: [IntelliDocs package](https://github.com/shortcutme/Sublime-IntelliDocs).

Try them all and find the one that suits you best.